# Error when running on TPU, "NotImplementedError: TPUStrategy.run(fn, ...) does not support pure eager execution....."

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tpu

I am trying to train my model over a colab TPU, but I am running into

> NotImplementedError: TPUStrategy.run(fn, ...) does not support pure eager execution. please make sure the function passed into `strategy.run` is a `tf.function` or `strategy.run` is called inside a `tf.function` if eager behavior is enabled.

Even though I don't believe I have any Python functions in my code.

Here is my best attempt to minimize the code in a colab notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Yo1mdnKA3DqZCr_UpZI4umY8tpBpDzS?usp=sharing

And here is the code pasted below

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip install transformers --q

!gcloud auth login

'''NEED TO RUN THIS CELL TWICE TO AVOID ERROR'''

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

project_id = 'machinelearning-264918'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}

!pip install tfa-nightly
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

from transformers import TFBertModel, AutoModel, TFRobertaModel
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense,
                                     Dropout)
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
import os
from copy import deepcopy 
from time import time

logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.info(tf.__version__)

autotune = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
    print('strategy.num_replicas_in_sync', strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
    logger.info('Running with TPUStrategy on TPU {} with {} cores '
                .format(tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'],
                        strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
    batch_size = 16 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
except Exception:
    # raise ValueError
    strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device='/gpu:0')
    logger.warning('Failed initializing TPU! Running on GPU')
    batch_size = 16

class Dora_A(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dora_A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bioRoberta = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained('allenai/biomed_roberta_base', from_pt=True)

    def call(self, inputIds):
        queryInputs, passageInputs = inputIds

        Q_outputs = self.bioRoberta(queryInputs)[0]
        P_outputs = self.bioRoberta(passageInputs)[0]

        dotProductMatrix = tf.linalg.matmul(Q_outputs, P_outputs, transpose_b=True, name='mm')

        return dotProductMatrix

@tf.function
def loss_fn(_, probs):
    '''
        1. Every sample is its own positive, and  the rest of the
            elements in the batch are its negative.
        2. Each TPU core gets 1/8 * global_batch_size elements, hence
            compute shape dynamically.
        3. Dataset produces dummy labels to make sure the loss_fn matches
            the loss signature of keras, actual labels are computed inside this
            function.
        4. Inputs are logits, for better numerical stability.
    '''
    bs = tf.shape(probs)[0]
    labels = tf.eye(bs, bs)
    return tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels,
                                              probs,
                                              from_logits=True)

CLS_inputID = tf.constant([0])
SEP_inputID = tf.constant([2])

def _parse_example(example_proto):
    features = {
        'bioRoberta_SentenceIndex': tf.io.VarLenFeature( dtype=tf.int64),
        'BioRoberta_IDs': tf.io.VarLenFeature( dtype=tf.int64),
    }

    parsed_example_dict = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    bertIds = parsed_example_dict['BioRoberta_IDs']
    bertIds = tf.sparse.to_dense(bertIds)
    bertIds = tf.cast(bertIds, dtype=tf.int32)

    queryPiece = tf.slice(bertIds, [0], [510])
    restPassagePiece = tf.slice(bertIds, [0], [510])
    # add special tokens for proper input into the model 
    queryBertInput = tf.concat( [CLS_inputID, queryPiece, SEP_inputID], axis=0)
    paragraphBertInput = tf.concat( [CLS_inputID, restPassagePiece, SEP_inputID], axis=0)

    return queryBertInput, paragraphBertInput

config_name = 'model_a'
base_dir = 'gs://a-dora-semantic-scholar'
model_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, config_name)
tensorboard_dir = os.path.join(model_dir, 'logs_' + str(time()))
tfrecords_pattern_train = os.path.join(base_dir, 'VersionA_00022*')
tfrecords_pattern_val = os.path.join(base_dir, 'VersionA_00022*')


if 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' in os.environ:
    print('Setting tf.data objects')
    with strategy.scope():
        filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(tfrecords_pattern_train)
        train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=autotune)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
                                        _parse_example, num_parallel_calls=autotune)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(130_000, seed=1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padding_values=(1, 1))
        train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(autotune)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())

with strategy.scope():
    model = Dora_A(dynamic=True)
    model.layers[0].trainable = False
    model.compile(loss=loss_fn,
                    optimizer=tfa.optimizers.AdamW(weight_decay=1e-5, 
                                                   learning_rate=1e-5, 
                                                   epsilon=1e-06))

model.fit(train_dataset)
```

And here's a Google Drive link to the sample data file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/106gSmcClyshu98SDQ9VsUVOhd-LYamVq/view?usp=sharing

This is the full error output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-50bee5f74f82> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_dataset)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_function(iterator)
    570       data = next(iterator)
    571       outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
--> 572           self.train_step, args=(data,))
    573       outputs = reduce_per_replica(
    574           outputs, self.distribute_strategy, reduction='first')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in run(self, fn, args, kwargs, options)
    166   def run(self, fn, args=(), kwargs=None, options=None):
    167     """See base class."""
--> 168     validate_run_function(fn)
    169 
    170     # Note: the target function is converted to graph even when in Eager mode,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in validate_run_function(fn)
    104       and not (callable(fn) and isinstance(fn.__call__, def_function.Function)):
    105     raise NotImplementedError(
--> 106         "TPUStrategy.run(fn, ...) does not support pure eager "
    107         "execution. please make sure the function passed into "
    108         "`strategy.run` is a `tf.function` or "

NotImplementedError: TPUStrategy.run(fn, ...) does not support pure eager execution. please make sure the function passed into `strategy.run` is a `tf.function` or `strategy.run` is called inside a `tf.function` if eager behavior is enabled.
```

Edit:

Following the comments, I decorated the call function, so that my model class looked like this

```
class Dora_A(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dora_A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bioRoberta = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained('allenai/biomed_roberta_base', from_pt=True)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputIds):
        queryInputs, passageInputs = inputIds

        Q_outputs = self.bioRoberta(queryInputs)[0]
        P_outputs = self.bioRoberta(passageInputs)[0]

        dotProductMatrix = tf.linalg.matmul(Q_outputs, P_outputs, transpose_b=True, name='mm')

        return dotProductMatrix
```

But I got the same error message.

I also tried decorating my tf.data parse function

```
CLS_inputID = tf.constant([0])
SEP_inputID = tf.constant([2])

@tf.function
def _parse_example(example_proto):
    features = {
        'bioRoberta_SentenceIndex': tf.io.VarLenFeature( dtype=tf.int64),
        'BioRoberta_IDs': tf.io.VarLenFeature( dtype=tf.int64),
    }

    parsed_example_dict = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    bertIds = parsed_example_dict['BioRoberta_IDs']
    bertIds = tf.sparse.to_dense(bertIds)
    bertIds = tf.cast(bertIds, dtype=tf.int32)

    queryPiece = tf.slice(bertIds, [0], [510])
    restPassagePiece = tf.slice(bertIds, [0], [510])
    # add special tokens for proper input into the model 
    queryBertInput = tf.concat( [CLS_inputID, queryPiece, SEP_inputID], axis=0)
    paragraphBertInput = tf.concat( [CLS_inputID, restPassagePiece, SEP_inputID], axis=0)

    return queryBertInput, paragraphBertInput
```

But got the same result.

Edit2:

I tried disabling eager execution (not recommended), but got an error when trying to compile the model.

It seems that when eager mode is disabled, I can not use distributed strategies for a subclassed model. The error message is

> ValueError: We currently do not support distribution strategy with a `Sequential` model that is created without `input_shape`/`input_dim` set in its first layer or a subclassed model.
> This happens during `model.compile`.

Here is a link to a different colab notebook I tried for this

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OhFgxbFoAEsLCDqpwBbe3P8owdJHMcUZ?usp=sharing

Here is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444486/use-tf-distribute-strategies-with-tf-keras-model-subclassing

Edit 3:

It's been suggested either to use the sequential or functional API, but it seems that I can only use model subclassing. I am unable to use Sequential in the non-minimalized version of my architecture because it has two pipelines. And the functional api has its own issues, which I describe it in this github issue ( https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40638#event-3468314954 ) but the summary is somehow the functional api seems to be deleting model weights and whole layers for my architecture.

Comment: Try decorating your `call()` method in your model with `tf.function`.

Comment: I tried it but got the same error message. I updated the post to mention what I tried.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, but have you tried wrapping you `model.fit(train_dataset)` into a `@tf.function`?

Comment: I tried but it gives 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax', I think because it's a function call, and not actually wrapping a function.